# Highchart not working on production environment

Tags: javascript, c#, azure, highcharts

I have a chart that is made with Highchart that contains 2 data axis that looks like this in dev environment:

[image: Local environment picture]

It looks fine and works like it is supposed to.
But when I publish the site one of the axis's disappears

[image: Published picture]

What can be the cause for this?
The project is in MVC and the graph also uses React.

Comment: Without code, nobody can help you. Upload your code in https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Reza I dont know how you want me to upload C# code to jsfiddle and for the second i cant share the code for other reasons

Comment: use this website https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you are loading all scripts in release mode, maybe you are including the reference only in development mode:

```
 <environment include="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    </environment>
```

Comment: I have 3 web.config files dev manage and release and in the reales one I had missed a few things.